# Nodejs Array prototype filter in a JSON

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, json

I'm trying a function to return some filtered string inside a JSON.
Could I have some advise?
Thank you
So in the example bellow my JSON is coming like this:

```
[
  {
    line: '{"status":"waiting"}'
  }
]


var body_W = [];
body_W.push({line: JSON.stringify(body)});
const result = body_W.filter(checkCha);
function checkCha(c) {
    return c.line == "status";
}
```

Comment: `c.line.startsWith('{"status"')` ?

Answer (score 1):

You are storing strings in your array, so you need to parse them into objects in your filter.

Something like this...

```
function checkCha(c) {
    return JSON.parse(c.line).status == "waiting";
}
```

or to check property

```
function checkCha(c) {
    return 'status' in JSON.parse(c.line)
}
```

Comment: Thanks Steven. I've quit from the array and used body.indexOf('waiting') accessing the object then treating if is < 0 or not.